# Flex AS3 Iphone - How to Open Native Maps Application?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I have a bunch of buttons that opens the default map application and puts something in the users system clipboard. It works fine on Android tablets, but the Iphone does nothing when the button is clicked. Here is the code:

```
  case "MapYummyYummy":
        System.setClipboard( "1665 Stelton Rd  Piscataway Nj 08901" )
        _callURL = "geo: 40.4978922, -74.4488224";
        var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_callURL);
        navigateToURL(targetURL);
        break;
```

Does anyone know the equivalent for this that will work on Iphone devices? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this setData method? (I have no experience with this one, but looks like a viable alternative).

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#setData()

iOS launch maps via URL reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Querying for a location:

http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino

setting a start and end for directions:

http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino

Hope it works for ya (looked up not tested).

Comment: ok that looks like a way to put data into the clipboard. Is there any way to have the Iphone automatically open up Maps?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't understand the extent of the issue, just saw the setClipboard call and thought it might be failing on iOS (have seen some "flakiness" between environments with the Clipboard calls before).  With regard to launching maps on iOS via a URL I'm editing above with a link.

Comment: awsome. I wonder how well the directions would work if I just put it from: Current Location to: San Francisco, CA